# Next auth not working properly in app dir

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am using next-auth for authentication, I am using app directory but the middleware.ts is not working properly

this is my folder structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYJtS.png)

**this is route.ts file**

```js
import axios from "axios";
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      type: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        email_id: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "email",
        },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const { email_id, password } = credentials as any;
        const { data: loginData } = await axios.put(
          "http://localhost:4300/auths/login",
          {
            email_id,
            password,
          }
        );
        if (loginData) {
          // Any object returned will be saved in `user` property of the JWT
          return loginData?.data;
        } else {
          // If you return null then an error will be displayed advising the user to check their details.
          return null;
          // You can also Reject this callback with an Error thus the user will be sent to the error page with the error message as a query parameter
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: { strategy: "jwt" },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
    error: "/",
  },
   callbacks: {
     async jwt({ token, user }) {
       return { ...token, ...user };
     },
     async session({ session, token, user }) {
       session.user = token;
       return session;
     },
   },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

and this is middleware.ts file

```js
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware"

export const config = { matcher: ["/consumers/dashboard", "/"] }
```

I am trying to redirect user if it is not logged in. but this is not working, I am still able to access dashboard without login. Please give me suggestions if something is going wrong.